# PIC18F2220 LED blinking program error

Tags: c, mplab, pic18

I am a beginner in PIC programming. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mUofSucHx_E&list=PL3lfkED2i6JcJH-OETxsI43e8M-7eLeL-) I have used to code my first program.

This is the code I have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "XC8.h"

void main(void)
{
   TRISBbits.RB0 = 0;
   OSCCON = 0x76;

   while(1)
   {
      LATBbits.LATB0 = ~LATBbits.LATB0;

      for (int countDelay=0; countDelay<20; countDelay++) __delay_ms(50);
   } 
}
```

And my `XC8.h` header file is:

```
// PIC18F2220 Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

// CONFIG1H
#pragma config OSC = RC         // Oscillator Selection bits (External RC oscillator, CLKO function on RA6)
#pragma config FSCM = OFF       // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal/External Switchover bit (Internal/External Switchover mode disabled)

// CONFIG2L
#pragma config PWRT = OFF       // Power-up Timer enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOR = OFF        // Brown-out Reset enable bit (Brown-out Reset disabled)
#pragma config BORV = 20        // Brown-out Reset Voltage bits (VBOR set to 2.0V)

// CONFIG2H
#pragma config WDT = ON         // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT enabled)
#pragma config WDTPS = 32768    // Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:32768)

// CONFIG3H
#pragma config CCP2MX = ON      // CCP2 MUX bit (CCP2 input/output is multiplexed with RC1)
#pragma config PBAD = ANA       // PORTB A/D Enable bit (PORTB<4:0> pins are configured as analog input channels on Reset)
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // MCLR Pin Enable bit (MCLR disabled; RE3 input is enabled in 40-pin devices only (PIC18F4X20))

// CONFIG4L
#pragma config STVR = ON        // Stack Full/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack full/underflow will cause Reset)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Single-Supply ICSP Enable bit (Single-Supply ICSP enabled)

// CONFIG5L
#pragma config CP0 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 0 (000200-0007FFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP1 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 1 (000800-000FFFh) not code-protected)

// CONFIG5H
#pragma config CPB = OFF        // Boot Block Code Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0001FFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM is not code-protected)

// CONFIG6L
#pragma config WRT0 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 0 (000200-0007FFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT1 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 1 (000800-000FFFh) not write-protected)

// CONFIG6H
#pragma config WRTC = OFF       // Configuration Register Write Protection bit (Configuration registers (300000-3000FFh) are not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTB = OFF       // Boot Block Write Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0001FFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTD = OFF       // Data EEPROM Write Protection bit (Data EEPROM is not write-protected)

// CONFIG7L
#pragma config EBTR0 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 0 (000200-0007FFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR1 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 1 (000800-000FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// CONFIG7H
#pragma config EBTRB = OFF      // Boot Block Table Read Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0001FFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000
```

I have followed all the steps as provided in the tutorial but I am getting the following error when I try to build the program.

```
make -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory 'E:/Projects/Coding/MPLABX/Programming/XC8/XC8.X'
make  -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk dist/default/production/XC8.X.production.hex
make[2]: Entering directory 'E:/Projects/Coding/MPLABX/Programming/XC8/XC8.X'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v1.42\bin\xc8.exe" --pass1  --chip=18F2220 -Q -G  --double=24 --float=24 --emi=wordwrite --opt=+asm,+asmfile,-speed,+space,-debug --addrqual=ignore --mode=free -P -N255 --warn=-3 --asmlist -DXPRJ_default=default  --summary=default,-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file --output=default,-inhx032 --runtime=default,+clear,+init,-keep,-no_startup,-download,+config,+clib,-plib   --output=-mcof,+elf:multilocs --stack=compiled:auto:auto:auto "--errformat=%f:%l: error: (%n) %s" "--warnformat=%f:%l: warning: (%n) %s" "--msgformat=%f:%l: advisory: (%n) %s"    -obuild/default/production/XC8.p1  XC8.c 
XC8.c:15: error: (192) undefined identifier "TRISBbits"
XC8.c:15: error: (196) struct/union required
XC8.c:16: error: (192) undefined identifier "OSCCON"
XC8.c:20: error: (192) undefined identifier "LATBbits"
XC8.c:20: error: (196) struct/union required
XC8.c:20: error: (196) struct/union required
XC8.c:22: warning: (361) function declared implicit int
(908) exit status = 1
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:100: recipe for target 'build/default/production/XC8.p1' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory 'E:/Projects/Coding/MPLABX/Programming/XC8/XC8.X'
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:84: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory 'E:/Projects/Coding/MPLABX/Programming/XC8/XC8.X'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make[2]: *** [build/default/production/XC8.p1] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 467ms)
```

Hope I have added sufficient input for the query. Since I am new to this section please feel free to ask for further information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You miss to include `#include <xc.h>`, instead you just set your configuration bits. The `xc.h` is the main header file that will include a lot of other header files that finally point to your special controller header file `#include <pic18f2220.h>`. It's done with `#ifdef` constructs that your MPLAB IDE should provide because you initially set the controller when creating a new project.

This [guide from Microchip](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002173A.pdf) is very helpful as beginning because it explains a lot.

If you don't include the `<xc.h>` header file the register names of your controller are not known to the compiler. That is the reason for your errors.

Comment: @AndreKampling Consider [nor is it polite...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266312/2410359)

Comment: @chuc: Thank you for your hint. I don't know that before and won't do that again.

Comment: @AndreKampling, got it